# Firebase hosting deployment strategy

Tags: deployment, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-hosting

I am currently using firebase hosting to host my static generated website. I would like to setup my CI/CD pipeline to automatically cancel the currently running build and deploy if a newer one is queued, but I'm a bit concerned as to what state the website will be in if I interrupt while firebase is deploying when a cancelation is triggered.

I've tried searching for the deployment strategy implemented by firebase hosting, but I can't seem to find anything on this. But hopefully this community has the answers I seek.

What deployment strategy is implemented in firebase hosting? Are there any gotchas in interrupting mid-deploy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Hosting uses [Versions and Releases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/api-deploy). If all the files of a version are never uploaded, a release won't happen.